# Delete Minecraft program with a batch code?

Tags: batch-file, file-io, minecraft

I need some help with a batch program to delete Minecraft on start up, because my friend likes to prank me with downloading Minecraft to my computer when I am away. Anyways, here is the code.

```
@echo off
cd/
CLS
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\William\Downloads\Minecraft.exe
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\William\Desktop\Minecraft.exe
rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\William\Appdata\Roaming\.Minecraft
MOVE "C:\Users\William\This pc\Documents\Minecraftdel.bat" "C:\Users\William\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
pause
```

I get the errors:

> The directory names is invalid. The system can not find the specified file.
>   The system can not find the specified file. The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The errors are in the order of the commands!

I have checked that the files are there and I did copy the path from the File Explorer.

Comment: Here's an idea: lock your computer when you leave your desk.

Comment: Yea that works, but can you help me with the code? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using the combination of echo and del to remove the directories, you should just use `rmdir`. `rmdir /S /Q C:\Users\Downloads\Minecraft`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the directory is invalid.. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? It doesn't exist? So, there was no Minecraft this time then? Anyway, you haven't enclosed the first argument of `MOVE` in double quotes. As a result, it will be interpreted as two arguments. (Don't know if that is actually the issue, you aren't telling us what the problem with your script is.)

Comment: @AndriyM I fixed the double quotes but I get syntax error... I downloaded minecraft to test it and stuff but I either won't accept my path or decline that the file exists. I copyed the path from the "top bar" and double checked for the file... /:

Comment: Please edit your question with your current code and exact error message/messages that you get.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here. When I said "double quotes", I just meant the `"` characters (as opposed to `'`, single quotes), I didn't mean that you should also "double" the character itself. It should be just `MOVE "source" "target"`, not `MOVE ""source"" "target"`.

Comment: .minecraft not .Minecraft

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `rmdir` to delete a file. Use the `DEL` command instead.

```
DEL C:\Users\William\Downloads\Minecraft.exe
DEL C:\Users\William\Desktop\Minecraft.exe
```

Comment: If I use the del commad it won't go automatic, but thanks anyways!

Comment: What do you mean "it won't go automatic"? If you mean it will prompt you for confirmation, it won't.